# Caveats of useing \begin{alignat*}{99}

Tags: alignat

I sometimes use the `alignat*` environment in the following way:

```
\begin{alignat*}{99}
   a & lot & of & ampersand & symbols & that & I \\
   do & not & really & want & to & count
\end{alignat*}
```

I understand that the number after `\begin{alignat*}` is supposed to be

```
(maxmimum number of & in a line  +  1) / 2,
```

but I really don't feel like counting them.

Using `pdflatex` this compiles fine and the output looks right to me. What are possible caveats of doing this, or is this even common practice? Is the answer different for the non-starred version?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96124/what-is-the-mandatory-argument-of-alignedat-for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one possible downside of using such a large value as `99` for `alignat*` is
that it may slow down processing, but these days that's not such a big deal.
however, i can't think of any situation in which nearly 200 segments could
possibly fit in the allowed width of a page.  even 25 should be adequate.

in regard to the non-starred version, that only adds an equation number.
the argument identifying number of segments is treated exactly the same.