# Properly typeset a system of equations

Tags: math-mode, align, alignment, alignat

I'm trying to typeset a system of linear equations which has multiple place to be aligned. Below is what I have achieved so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
    \left\{
        \begin{alignedat}{5}
            &x &+& &&y &=& &&0\\
            2&x &+& 3&&y &=& &&0
        \end{alignedat}
    \right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see from the above picture, the spacing seems to be a little bit strange (though I cannot tell exactly where is wrong). Is there some way to improve this result? (I'm using `alignat` in the MWE, but you may also use `array` or other methods if better result can be gained.)

Comment: I think this has been asked many times, no? One quick way in LaTeX is to use the `systeme` package.

Comment: @mickep Thank you for the recommendation, this seems to be a pretty nice package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I would probably use this form, with alignment points between the coefficients and the variables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
    \left\{
        \begin{alignedat}{3}
             &x +{}&  &y &&=0\\
            2&x +{}& 3&y &&=0
        \end{alignedat}
    \right.
\]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [systeme](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/systeme)-based solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}
\[
\systeme{x+y=0,2x+3y=0}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Two examples:

- use of `array`
- use of a bit simplified your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
    \left\{
        \begin{array}{rcrl}
            x & + &  y & = 0\\
           2x & + & 3y & = 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
\]
or
\[
    \left\{
        \begin{alignedat}{3}
            x & + {} &  y & = 0\\
           2x & + {} & 3y & = 0
        \end{alignedat}
    \right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Considered is @David Carlisle comment.

Comment: Thank you for this. Would you mind explaining a little regarding how does your `alignedat` work? I used to think that each line of the content of `alignedat` start with a single `&`, and then has two `&`s each time.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you are right. Corrected now.

Comment: @Jinwen, good explanation about `alinedat` you can find in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96124/what-is-the-mandatory-argument-of-alignedat-for