# Reduce horizontal spacing of aligned equations with normal text in math mode

Tags: equations, align

In the following example, I was wondering how to "properly" eliminate (or reduce) the horizontal spacing between "minimize"/"subject to" and the corresponding equations, while keeping the alignment at the first letters of the two words, and at the equal signs, in addition, all equations numbered.

By "properly", I suggest not to use negative horizontal spacing `\hspace{-...}`.

Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        &\text{minimize} &S(f) &=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^{\prime\prime}(x)^2 \, \text{d}x  \label{eq:min-energy} \\
        &\text{subject~to} &f(x_i) &= y_i, \enspace \text{for} \; i=1,\ldots,m  \label{eq:interp-cond} \\
        & &f^{\prime\prime}(x_1) &= f^{\prime\prime}(x_m)=0  \label{eq:natural-bc} \\
        & &f &\in C^2(-\infty,\infty).  \label{eq:C2-constraint}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the automatic spacing inserted by `align`, you should have a look at `alignat`. ([Others have done a better job than I can explaining how to use it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200813/119), so I will just include an example below of what I think has relatively pleasant spacing.)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{10}
        &\text{minimize} &S(f) &=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^{\prime\prime}(x)^2 \, \text{d}x  \label{eq:min-energy} \\
        &\text{subject~to}\; &f(x_i) &= y_i, \enspace \text{for} \; i=1,\ldots,m  \label{eq:interp-cond} \\
        & &f^{\prime\prime}(x_1) &= f^{\prime\prime}(x_m)=0  \label{eq:natural-bc} \\
        & &f &\in C^2(-\infty,\infty).  \label{eq:C2-constraint}
    \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Notes:

1. After `\text{subject~to}` I inserted `\;`. Because of the `f''` on the next line, I find that without the extra space it looks a bit cramped. You may decide otherwise.
2. I specified `10` as the [mandatory argument for alignat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96124/what-is-the-mandatory-argument-of-alignedat-for) because I am lazy; see the link for explanation.

---

My personal opinion, however, is that it is better in this case not to align at the equality signs. I think something like

```
\begin{alignat}{10}
    &\text{minimize} &&S(f) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^{\prime\prime}(x)^2 \, \text{d}x  \label{eq:min-energy} \\
    & &&f(x_i) = y_i, \enspace \text{for} \; i=1,\ldots,m  \label{eq:interp-cond} \\
    &\text{subject to}\, \smash{\left\lbrace\vphantom{\begin{array}{l} f \\ f \\ f\end{array}} \right.} &&f^{\prime\prime}(x_1) = f^{\prime\prime}(x_m)=0  \label{eq:natural-bc} \\
    & &&f \in C^2(-\infty,\infty).  \label{eq:C2-constraint}
\end{alignat}
```

looks better.

[image]

(There are other methods of getting a large brace spanning multiple lines in an `alignat`, the one given above is a bit of a hack that nonetheless doesn't require any additional packages. If you are willing to be less lazy, the `\vphantom{\begin{array}... \end{array}}` can be replaced with `\rule{0pt}{<height>}` with a well-chosen height; 5.5ex for the height seems to work ok.)

Comment: Thank you for your help, @WillieWong.

Answer (score 4):

This puts the text left aligned in constant width boxes to the left of the alignment point.  `\mathllap` overlaps part of this space, also using the alignment point.  The choice of the width is a question of aesthetics.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \makebox[1.25in][l]{minimize}\mathllap{S(f)} &=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^{\prime\prime}(x)^2 \, \text{d}x  \label{eq:min-energy} \\
        \makebox[1.25in][l]{subject~to}\mathllap{f(x_i)} &= y_i, \enspace \text{for} \; i=1,\ldots,m  \label{eq:interp-cond} \\
        f^{\prime\prime}(x_1) &= f^{\prime\prime}(x_m)=0  \label{eq:natural-bc} \\
        f &\in C^2(-\infty,\infty).  \label{eq:C2-constraint}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

---

Frankly, I prefer a flalign solution:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool
\begin{document}
    \begin{flalign}
        &\text{minimize} & S(f) &=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^{\prime\prime}(x)^2 \, \text{d}x  \label{eq:min-energy} && \\
        &\text{subject~to} & f(x_i) &= y_i, \enspace \text{for} \; i=1,\ldots,m  \label{eq:interp-cond} && \\
        && f^{\prime\prime}(x_1) &= f^{\prime\prime}(x_m)=0  \label{eq:natural-bc} && \\ %actually, on needed in one line
        && f &\in C^2(-\infty,\infty).  \label{eq:C2-constraint}
    \end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `optidef` package to  reduce the horizontal spacing between "minimize"/"subject to" and the corresponding equations. Here there is a example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{optidef}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{mini!}<b>
{}{S(f) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f''^2(x) \, \textup{d}x  \label{eq:min-energy}}{}{}
\addConstraint {f(x_i)}{= y_i,}{ \textup{for} \; i=1,\ldots, m  \label{eq:interp-cond} }
\addConstraint { f''(x_1) }{= f''(x_m)=0  \label{eq:natural-bc}}{}
\addConstraint { f}{\in C^2(-\infty,\infty).  \label{eq:C2-constraint}}{}
\end{mini!}
\end{document}
```

[image]