# Equation alignment of an optimization problem

Tags: equations, amsmath, alignment, aligned

In the following excerpt of a write-up, I was wondering how to left-align `\hat{L}` and `f` on the second column of the first two lines. The best I could produce is below.

Thanks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{extbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{aligned}
            &\text{maximize}   && \hat{L}(f) \\
            &\text{subject~to} & f &\in H_0^1[a,b], \\
            && \int_a^b f(x) \diff x &= 1, \\
            && f(x) &\geq 0  \text{ for all } x \in [a,b].
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do they need to line up with the integral on the third line?

Comment: No, @KennethOdle.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: What's the (typographic) purpose of aligning the `\in` symbol in line 2, the `=` symbol in line 3, and the `\geq` symbol in line 4 \?

Comment: @Mico: You can say "typographic preference". Your solution is also good, and I'm considering it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just playing around with the placement of `\hat{L}(f)`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

Original:
\[
  \begin{aligned}
    &\text{maximize}   &                       & \hat{L}(f) \\
    &\text{subject~to} &                     f &\in H_0^1[a,b], \\
    &                  & \int_a^b f(x) \diff x &= 1, \\
    &                  &                  f(x) &\geq 0  \text{ for all } x \in [a,b].
  \end{aligned}
\]

Updated:
\[
  \begin{aligned}
    &\text{maximize}   & \mathrlap{\hat{L}(f)}\phantom{f} \\
    &\text{subject~to} &                      f &\in H_0^1[a,b], \\
    &                  &  \int_a^b f(x) \diff x &= 1, \\
    &                  &                   f(x) &\geq 0  \text{ for all } x \in [a,b].
  \end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

The placement of `\hat{L}(f)` is to the left of an `f` in a zero-width math box that is left-aligned (has a `r`ight over`lap`) using `\mathrlap`. This requires [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) which loads [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

Comment: Thanks, @Werner, for the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Is a two-column layout ok? (What would be point of aligning the `\in` symbol on line 2, the `=` symbol on line 3, and the `\geq` symbol on line 4 with each other?)

Remove the `\textstyle` and `\smash` directives in line 3 if you want a large integral symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{extbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  &\text{maximize}        && \hat{L}(f) \\[\jot] % insert some whitespace padding
  &\text{subject to\quad} && f \in H_0^1 [a,b], \\
  &                       && \textstyle\smash{\int_a^b} f(x)\diff x=1, \\
  &                       && f(x)\ge0  \text{ for all $x\in[a,b]$}.
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [**optidef**](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/optidef/optidef.pdf) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}
\begin{maxi}<b>
{ }{ \hat{L}(f) }{}{}
\addConstraint { f \in H_0^1 [a,b] }{  }
\addConstraint {\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x }{=1}
\addConstraint {f(x)}{\geq 0  \textup{ for all } x \in [a,b].}
\end{maxi}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is a bit amusing that you basically [gave the same answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688121/119) to the same question asker about 1 month ago.

Comment: @WillieWong When I find maximize or minimize I always use optidef package :-). Thank you so much for your advice.

Comment: Thank you, @Sebastiano, for your answer.

Comment: @AEW You're welcome.